# C# Parser Bug on delegate?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 0 arguments.' Is this a C# compiler bug (lambdas + two projects)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466859/delegate-system-action-does-not-take-0-arguments-is-this-a-c-compiler-bug)

When I was doing a testing framework that used heavy lambda usage I thing I stumbled on a parser bug.

```
public class CSpecTestRunnerSpec : CSpecFacade<CSpecTestRunner>
{
    public CSpecTestRunnerSpec()
        : base(new CSpecTestRunner())
    {
        CreateOperations();
    }

    private MyClassSpec myClassSpec;
    private DescribeAll run_on_type;

    protected override void BeforeOperation()
    {
        myClassSpec = new MyClassSpec();
    }

    private void CreateOperations()
    {
        run_on_type =
           (@it, @do) =>
           {
               @it("Runs all of the operations contained in a type");
               @do.RunTestOnType(myClassSpec.GetType());
           };
    }
```

DescribeAll delegate comes from the base class and it's interface looks like so:

EDIT the code looks like so:

```
public delegate void DescribeAll(Action<string> description, TClass objSpec);
```

The exception I'm getting is "Delegate Action does not take 1 arguments" But it totally does! and after adding a dummy delegate to code of my class:

```
    private Action<string> dummy;
```

It started to work. :-)

By contrast the same code works without errors in mono without the dummy delegate it was tested on multiple machines with NET 3.5 and 4.0.

So my question is, is this a bug on the compiler side or my side?, and how to resolve the issue?

p.s the framework is on [codeplex](http://cspec.codeplex.com/) so you can get the full code and test it yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### UPDATE:

The bug has been fixed in C# 5. Apologies again for the inconvenience, and thanks for the report.

---

That is a known bug in the compiler, though it is not in the parser; it's in the interaction between the semantic analyzer and the metadata import cache. My analysis of the bug is here:

['Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 0 arguments.' Is this a C# compiler bug (lambdas + two projects)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466859/delegate-system-action-does-not-take-0-arguments-is-this-a-c-compiler-bug/4467128#4467128)

This one was my fault; I apologize for the inconvenience.  We'll try to get it fixed for the next version.

Answer (score 2):

There is a delegate type `Action` that takes no arguments. I think you want `Action<T>`

```
public delegate void DescribeAll(Action<string> description, TClass objSpec);
```

or

```
public delegate void DescribeAll(Action<object> description, TClass objSpec);
```

or

```
public delegate void DescribeAll<T>(Action<T> description, TClass objSpec);
```

Comment: Yes this could work but then I would need to explicitly state that I want a string. DescribeAll<string> run_on_type and I don't want tat as @it will always be a string. EDIT: original code edited I already have that, and it doesn't work

Comment: Ok. I appended two alternatives

Comment: Nothing works :-) it looks like C# bug, any idea where can I post it?