# Strange Behaviour Using Delegates and Lambdas

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, lambda

As a means of introducing lazy formatting evaluation in a library I am developing, I have defined the delegates

```
public delegate string MessageFormatterDelegate(string message, params object[] arguments);
public delegate string MessageFormatterCallback(MessageFormatterDelegate formatterDelegate);
```

and something along the lines of the following class

```
public static class TestClass
{
    public static string Evaluate(MessageFormatterCallback formatterCallback)
    {
        return (formatterCallback(String.Format));
    }
}
```

However, this is behaving strangely enough: when running from an **external** project, the statement

```
Console.WriteLine(TestClass.Evaluate(message => message("{0},{1},{2}", 1, 2, 3)));
```

does **not** compile, failing with the error

```
Error   1   Delegate 'MessageFormatterDelegate' does not take 4 arguments
```

while

```
Console.WriteLine(TestClass.Evaluate((MessageFormatterDelegate message) => message("{0},{1},{2}", 1, 2, 3)));
```

compiles and works with no problems, printing `1,2,3` in the console. Why do I have to qualify the `message` argument with `MessageFormatterDelegate` type in the second lambda expression? Is there any way to circunvent this behaviour?

Comment: Interesting. Does look like a bug of sorts. Have you test this with all the different C# compiler versions to see if it has been fixed?

Comment: Thanks leppie. In fact, I have tested it under Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition with SP1 freshly installed.

Comment: @DotNetStudent: And does it work there, or is that where it's failing for you? It should be fine - see my answer.

Comment: Sorry Jon. I forgot to add the "external project" part in the first post! In the same project it works, but not from an external project.

Comment: lambdas use implicit typing, it cannot translate your first attempt because you have provided it with an array of some integral type. if you had passed in "{0},{1},{2}", new object[] { 1, 2, 3 } it should have worked. Similarly, your explicit second lambda negates the necessity for implicit typing. (ahh, I missed the added external project detail..)

Comment: @mtijn: BS! There is no generics involved here, so no type guessing...

Comment: @leppie: Inferring the lambda expression delegate type. ( (c) Jon Skeet :-P )

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 0 arguments.' Is this a C# compiler bug (lambdas + two projects)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466859/delegate-system-action-does-not-take-0-arguments-is-this-a-c-sharp-compiler)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, I've now got a much shorter example *and* a workaround.

First source file, `External.cs`:

```
public delegate string Callback(System.Action<string> x);
```

Second source file, `Test.cs`:

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Callback callback = action => action("hello");
    }
}
```

Compile with:

```
> csc /target:library External.cs
> csc Test.cs /r:External.cs
```

Error:

> Delegate 'Action' does not take 1 arguments

Workaround: change the body of the `Main` method to:

```
Callback callback = action => action.Invoke("hello");
```

... or include the delegate declaration in the same assembly which uses it.

This definitely looks like a bug to me. When the compiler knows that the type of `foo` is a particular delegate type, then `foo(arg)` and `foo.Invoke(arg)` should be equivalent.

Will mail Eric Lippert...

Comment: Sorry Jon. I forgot to add the "external project" part in the first post! In the same project it works, but not from an external project.

Comment: @DotNetStudent: So how much is in this "external" project? All but the call? I've a feeling I *may* have seen this before...

Comment: On this first project (for example, a DLL) is the definition of the delegates and of the `TestClass` class. On the second project (for example, a Console Application) are the `Console.WriteLine(TestClass...))` calls.

Comment: @DotNetStudent: Okay, will try to reproduce.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Type inference? I see no generics here. Why should type inference even come up in this conversation?

Comment: @leppie: Inferring the lambda expression delegate type.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ok, I kinda agree, but with a known delegate type, it should already know what the type of the parameter is.

Comment: @leppie: You'd think - but apparently not. It's possible I shouldn't call this type inference - I'll check.

Comment: @leppie: Okay, I've checked - it's still called type inference when a method group conversion is involved (section 7.5.2.13) but I don't think it is for anonymous function conversion.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Too technical for me, seeing that it is weekend here already ;p

Comment: @JonSkeet: This 'cross assembly' bug does not actually surprise me. A long long time ago (before `InternalsVisibleTo`), I ran into a 'problem' where attributes on non-public fields would not be reflectable at all.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the known bug described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466859/delegate-system-action-does-not-take-0-arguments-is-this-a-c-sharp-compiler/4467128 (See my answer to that question for details.) Jon, do you concur that this is a duplicate? If you think this is a different bug then I'll bring it to David's attention and we'll get a bug entered for C# 5. Thanks, and apologies for the error.

Comment: @EricLippert: Certainly looks like it. The workaround of explicitly calling `Invoke` may be an extra bit of information to record internally, if you haven't already got it. I guess it's probably worth checking against the C# 5 compiler, if that's meant to have fixed the other one :) (I can check against the VS 11 Preview when I get home if that would be useful, but not right now.)

Answer (score 12):

### UPDATE:

The bug has been fixed in C# 5. Apologies again for the inconvenience, and thanks for the report.

---

This appears to be a duplicate of the known bug described here:

['Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 0 arguments.' Is this a C# compiler bug (lambdas + two projects)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466859/delegate-system-action-does-not-take-0-arguments-is-this-a-c-sharp-compiler/4467128)

See my answer to that question for details.

It was also reported here:

[C# Parser Bug on delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717637/c-sharp-parser-bug-on-delegate)

This bug was my bad; I apologize for the error. We'll try to get a fix in C# 5.

If you think that you have actually found a *different* bug, please let me know and we'll start an investigation.

And thanks for the report, I appreciate it.