# Is using Action.Invoke considered best practice?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

If I have the below code, should I just call the Action or should it call Action.Invoke?

```
public class ClassA
{
  public event Action<string> OnAdd;

  private void SomethingHappened()
  {
    if (OnAdd != null)
     OnAdd("It Happened"); //Should it be OnAdd.Invoke("It Happened") ???????
  }
}

public class ClassB
{

  public ClassB()
  {
    var myClass = new ClassA();
    myClass.OnAdd += Add;
  }

  private void Add(string Input)
  {
    //do something
  }  
}
```

Comment: In c# 6 it may end up being more popular to use the new  `OnAdd?.Invoke("It Happened");` syntax

Comment: A little more detail to the comment above. That example is using a feature of C# 6, the Null-Conditional Operator. The ? operator prevents the calling of Invote method if OnAdd is null thus preventing an exception. This allows the writing of code that foregoes the explicit null checking show in the answers below. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx for more detail.

Comment: Some comparison here: https://jacksondunstan.com/articles/3283 .

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The two are equivalent, the compiler converts `OnAdd("It Happened");` into `OnAdd.Invoke("It Happened");` for you.

I guess it's a matter of preference, however I personally prefer the terser form.

As an aside, it is generally preferable to take a local copy of a class level delegate before invoking it to avoid a race condition whereby `OnAdd` is not null at the time that it is checked, but is at the time that it is invoked:

```
private void SomethingHappened()
{
  Action<string> local = OnAdd;
  if (local != null)
  {
    local("It Happened");
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the difference in the race example, sorry

Comment: @Jon: Think about if there are two threads involved, and one thread sets `OnAdd` to null *after* the other thread has tested for it being null but before invoking it... in your code, you'd end up with a `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 26):

Something I noticed on this with the latest C# 6 release as it may encourage `Invoke` to be used more and thought I'd add it to this old question in case it helps someone:

"Old" way:

```
Action<string> doSomething = null; // or not null
if (doSomething != null)
    doSomething("test");
```

Possible pragmatic way (similar to empty event delegate pattern):

```
Action<string> doSomethingPragmatic = s => { }; // empty - might be overwritten later
doSomethingPragmatic("test");
```

C# 6:

```
Action<string> doSomethingCs6 = null; // or not null
doSomethingCs6?.Invoke("test");

// Not valid C#:
// doSomethingCs6?("test")
// doSomethingCs6?.("test")
```

Comment: ReSharper encourages this new C# 6 style.

Answer (score 19):

The two constructs are perfectly equivalent.

```
OnAdd("It Happened");
```

is just syntactic sugar. Behind the scenes the compiler emits a call to `Action<T>.Invoke` in the resulting MSIL. So use the one that's more readable to you (for me `OnAdd("It Happened");` is readable enough).

Answer (score 7):

They're exactly equivalent unless you run into a [very strange bug around anonymous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128171/strange-behaviour-using-delegates-and-lambdas).

Personally I *typically* use the shortcut form, but just occasionally it ends up being more readable to explicitly call `Invoke`. For example, you might have:

```
if (callAsync)
{
    var result = foo.BeginInvoke(...);
    // ...
}
else
{
    foo.Invoke(...);
    // ...
}
```

Here the explicit use of `Invoke` is useful for symmetry.

See section 15.4 of the C# 4 spec for more details of delegate invocation, although it doesn't explicitly specify it in terms of calling the `Invoke` method.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use `Invoke()` since this allows me to handle a possible null reference with `myAction?.Invoke()`.