# Do you need to use Invoke on Action?

Tags: c#, action

I was looking around for an answer to this but couldn't find anything related. I have learnt to use `Action.Invoke()` when using an `Action`, but do you actually need to use `.Invoke`?

Say I have this Action:

```
Action<int> action = x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(x + 1);
};
```

Do I use:

```
action.Invoke(2);
```

or

```
action(2);
```

What's the difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its the same thing, `action(2);` basically calls `action.Invoke(2);`
The compiler converts `action(2)` into `action.Invoke(2);`

**From a [post from Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259470/is-using-action-invoke-considered-best-practice):**

> Personally I typically use the shortcut form, but just occasionally it
>   ends up being more readable to explicitly call Invoke. For example,
>   you might have:

```
if (callAsync)
{
    var result = foo.BeginInvoke(...);
    // ...
}
else
{
    foo.Invoke(...);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The latter is purely syntactic sugar for the former - there is no difference (both are also synchronous).

It is nice to just be able to run the action like a method instead of the intermediary `Invoke` call.

`Invoke` has a counterpart `BeginInvoke` for asynchronous invocation.