# Action.Invoke: Where is it written exactly?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, delegates, action, documentation

I've encountered the next piece of code:

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,[CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "",  Action onChanged = null)
 {
     if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
        return false;
           
      backingStore = value;   
      onChanged?.Invoke();   
      OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);     
                                                                        
      return true;                                           
 }
```

By this code, it is clear to see that every Action can call the method Invoke().
I wanted to read about this method in the documentation for [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=netcore-3.1) and it's not there.
I thought maybe it is in [Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate?view=netcore-3.1). It's not.

Where is this method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is using Action.Invoke considered best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259470/is-using-action-invoke-considered-best-practice)

Comment: @Jawad Hi, not it isn't .It discusses Action.Invoke - whether it is good to use it or not, but doens't deal with the question "Where is it written".