# "Could not load type 'System.Action' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=3.7.0.0" exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, nunit

I'm experiencing a very strange issue:

I use the NUnit framework for testing in WP7 project.  Currently im trying to use a Silverlight Unit Test Framework to run tests on device (using `NUnitTestProvider`).

Everything works fine except for tests which use `System.Action`. In these tests I get a **runtime error** :

> Could not load type 'System.Action' from assembly 'mscorlib,
>   Version=3.7.0.0

For example this doesn't work (non-generic System.Action)

```
public void MethodThatAcceptsRawAction(System.Action callback);
...
MethodThatAcceptsRawAction( () => Console.WriteLine("Hi"));
```

But this will work

```
public void MethodThatAcceptsOneArgAction(System.Action<object> exCallback);
...
MethodThatAcceptsOneArgAction( (ex) => Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()));
```

I checked public types in **mscorlib.dll** that was in memory, it has no `System.Action`, but has `System.Action'1` type. Looks like **System.Core.dll** has `System.Action`.

Microsoft decided to split System.Action variations between two libraries but runtime binder doesn't know where to look for the type.

Maybe someone had the same problem or at least knows something to look at?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could this be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466859/delegate-system-action-does-not-take-0-arguments-is-this-a-c-sharp-compiler ?

Comment: Nope, i have a runtime error and the link is about compiler time. But thanks for this link. It is quite interesting!

Comment: Yes it really is! Ok then, let's wait for enlightenment from other sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, looks like the solution was found.

Default WP7 project template defines **mscorlib** reference. This is a bit weird, i thought that it is always referred by compiler (if used without /nostdlib key).

I removed this reference and everything is is okay now.

P.S. I dont mark this post as answer, probably someone can explain this behavior. This would be a real answer.